# Видимость Button'a при написании текста в editText

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Когда я пишу текст в EditText(multiline) - проподают кнопки  ,но после окончания писания кнопки снова появляются .

Пример 1(во время писания текста):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример 2(после написания текста):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего они уползают наверх, когда появляется раскладка.